# More TurtleBot_dashboard problems

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-dashboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now I can get the dashboard pulled up on my turtle bot computer, but not my workstation. In addition, I have no idea how to change the ROS Master URI to the TurtleBot. Please help, I think I am almost at the point to start working on my robotics project!

-Parker

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11132/more-turtlebot_dashboard-problems/) by [ParkerGibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/978/parkergibbons/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Watch the TurtleBot dashboard video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDU1Wc9SO7Q.

To set your ROS_MASTER_URI

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://<TURTLEBOT_IP>:11311
```

replace < TURTLEBOT_IP > with the IP address of the TurtleBot

to determine the IP address of the TurtleBot

```
ifconfig
```

you should see something similar to:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:36800562 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36800562 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3320894268 (3.3 GB)  TX bytes:3320894268 (3.3 GB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:5d:60:7d:22:e6  
          inet addr:10.0.129.60  Bcast:10.0.129.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4a5d:60ff:fe7d:22e6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:475034 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:292561 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:360404726 (360.4 MB)  TX bytes:49527301 (49.5 MB)
```

in the above case < TURTLEBOT_IP >=10.0.129.60

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-09-12**:
You can get better performance in X forwarding by also enabling compression with -C, e.g.: `ssh -XC turtlebot`.

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-10**:
to install your ROS on your ubuntu workstation follow the instructions here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/diamondback/SDK%20Setup/Ubuntu%20Deb

**Comment by [ParkerGibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/978/parkergibbons/) on 2011-09-09**:
Woo! It's working now with the -X command. Thank you so much!

**Comment by [ParkerGibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/978/parkergibbons/) on 2011-09-09**:
Would I just install the desktop one with " sudo service apt-get ros-diamondback-turtlebot-desktop "?

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-09**:
ahhh you're trying to view the dashboard over ssh.. typically you would install ros-diamondback-turtlebot-desktop on your workstation computer and run the dashboard locally (on the workstation computer) in order to do it over ssh you need to to X forwarding by doing ssh -X when ssh-ing

**Comment by [ParkerGibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/978/parkergibbons/) on 2011-09-09**:
" Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?", when I type "rosrun turtlebot_dashboard turtlebot_dashboard&". What is wrong?

**Comment by [ParkerGibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/978/parkergibbons/) on 2011-09-09**:
@mwise_wg It has helped me set the URI, but I still can't get the dashboard to open on my workstation. I get the message

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-07**:
@ParkerGibbons did this help you?